# Symfony2 Doctrine entity class generation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried to generate an annotation php class from my database.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

But doctrine detect just id field, why?
So why is not automatic?

( "users" table fields: id, username, password )

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that command you're trying to generate an entity from a mapping file.
If you want to generate entity (entities) from db tables - and if I understood correctly you are - you should use

```
doctrine:mapping:import
```

and then use

```
doctrine:generate:entities
```